# Trouble Installing BIOVIA DS 2020 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bash, software-installation, scripts

I have been checking all system requirements and essential hardware but it does not work out. Please, anyone help me out!

```
$ chmod +x BIOVIA_2020.DS2020Client.bin
$ ./BIOVIA_2020.DS2020Client.bin 
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing 'DS Client and extracting files, please wait ......'  100%  
./install_DSClient.sh: 49: ./install_DSClient.sh: [[: not found
./install_DSClient.sh: 70: ./install_DSClient.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Comment: Syntactical error in the script? What is at line `49` and `70`?

Comment: Ubuntu is [NOT a supported operating system](https://www.3dsbiovia.com/products/collaborative-science/biovia-discovery-studio/requirements/technical-requirements-2020.html).